# Como cancelar o editar archivo apk de lanzamiento a produccion en google play console

Tags: android, app, control-de-versiones, google-play-console

tengo un problema, lance mi App en version Alfa en la play console hace 1 semana y paso a estado de publicada, luego de testear, modifique algunas cosas y entre ellas agregue un boton para testar mi base de datos el cual olvide retirar, y luego la subi en modo produccion el dia de hoy.

La pregunta es si puedo cancelar esta publicacion ó eliminar y subir un nuevo archivo apk,actualmente me aparece como si ya estuviera publicada, pero no aparece en la play store, esto supongo es normal ya que tarda hasta 7 dias, pero por esto mismo no me deja eliminarla de manera normal, esto me aparece cuando ingreso en la play console:

NombreDeMiApp -> Admin de lanzamientos -> Versiones de App -> Produccion -> Administrar

```
Hoy, 11:44: Lanzamiento completo.    
(Se promovió desde la versión Alfa 1.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Si publicaste a producciòn y esta no esta desplegada aùn completamente para el total de los usuarios, puedes detener el lanzamiento, de esta forma quien trate de acceder a tu aplicaciòn desde Google Play no podrà encontrar la aplicaciòn que tiene problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De otra forma si publicaste para el 100% de los usuarios tu aplicaciòn ya no podràs detener su lanzamiento.

**Lo que tienes que realizar es crear ràpidamente un .apk o android App Bundle con la correcciòn, recuerda que es muy importante que este tenga un `versionCode` mayor, el cual puedes modificar desde tu archivo `build.gradle`.**

---

Regularmente debes promover tu aplicaciòn de Alpha a Beta de esta forma probar y detectar un posible problema, si promueves de Alpha a Producciòn puedes tener problemas como el que describes.